# Not sure how to store objects with keys - Java

Tags: java, dictionary

As of now my Java code has something like - A unique int ID(TV Channel Number) and and Object of TVShows - The TV channels have shows that relate to them.

So... A TV Channel(int) can have one to many shows(objects).

I am currently storing my TVChannels and shows in a hashmap - Key(int -ChannelNumber) - Value (TvShow)

The problem is the hashmap can only store a one to one relationship - 1 Key has 1 Value.

I need advice within java on how to link my unique TV Channel ID with my many shows.

e.g. ChannelID 101 - Simpsons, Friends, GoT. etc...
     ChannelID 102 - TopGear, News. etc...

I need to be able to search a ChannelID and retrieve all the related shows to that ChannelID. I'm just looking for advice on the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Just use Map<Integer, List<TVShow>>

Comment: Combine the key to be a combination of `int` (channel) and `Date` (start time)

Answer (score -1):

For headstart ,an approach as follows

```
 List<String> ll = new  ArrayList<String>();
 ll.add("Simpsons");
 ll.add("Friends"); 
 HashMap<Integer,List<String>> hMap = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>> ();
 hMap.put(101,ll);
 System.out.println(hMap);

 System.out.println(hMap.get(101));
```

Comment: Why is it -ve flagged ? trying to understand